# Swift Dictionary with Protocol Type as Key

Tags: ios, macos, swift, dictionary, protocols

short question here:

I got a protocol `protocol SCResourceModel {..}` and a dictionary which shall use this protocol type as key: `[SCResourceModel : String]`. 
This obviously does not work, as a key in a dictionary has to conform to the protocol `Hashable`. Making my `SCResourceModel` inherit from `Hashable` or trying something like this `[protocol<SCResourceModel, Hashable> : String]` obviously does not work as well, since `Hashable` or `Equatable` can only be used as generic constraints and not as types themselves.

I watched the WWDC 2015 and in Swift 2.0 it is possible to add constraints to a protocol like: `protocol SCResourceModel where Self: Hashable {..}` which directly addresses this issue (very nice).

Anyway, my question is: Can I do something similar with the current Swift 1.2 version and somehow use this protocol as the key of a dictionary? Or can anyone propose a nice workaround or something else that I might have overlooked?

The only solution I see at the moment for Swift 1.2, is to transform the protocol to a class which inherits from e.g. NSObject and must be subclassed for further usage in my API.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You probably mean Swift 1.2, there's no 1.3. It should work like `protocol SCResourceModel : Hashable {}` Or is there an error for you? If so, show your (minimal) code

Comment: I fixed the version :) Your suggestion does not work, as this makes `SCResourceModel` a `Hashable` Type. It is not allowed to use this as Type only as generic constraint (it does not compile either). The code is pretty much already in the question. A protocol and a dictionary, two lines. Let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 6):

I would probably think in the direction of:

```
protocol SCResourceModel {
    var hashValue: Int { get }
    func isEqualTo(another: SCResourceModel) -> Bool

    // ...
}

struct SCResourceModelWrapper: Equatable, Hashable {
    let model: SCResourceModel

    var hashValue: Int {
        return model.hashValue ^ "\(model.dynamicType)".hashValue
    }
}

func == (lhs: SCResourceModelWrapper, rhs: SCResourceModelWrapper) -> Bool {
    return lhs.model.isEqualTo(rhs.model)
}

struct SCResourceModelDictionary<T> {
    private var storage = [SCResourceModelWrapper: T]()

    subscript(key: SCResourceModel) -> T? {
        get {
            return storage[SCResourceModelWrapper(model: key)]
        }
        set {
            storage[SCResourceModelWrapper(model: key)] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice workaround to create a custom dictionary. I like it!

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so as far as I can tell, there isn't a really nice way to have the protocol itself as a key. But I'm pretty sure a string version of the protocol name would work nicely for your purpose. As a bonus, you can also have protocol objects as the value in a dictionary (if that is useful in your circumstance)

Thing is, I can't find a nice way to do this in Swift either, but here is what I've come up with in Objective-C, maybe you would be better than me at finding a way to do this in Swift:

```
// With a protocol declared...
@protocol TestProtocol <NSObject>
@end

@implementation

// Inside the implementation you can use NSStringFromProtocol()
Protocol *proto = @protocol(TestProtocol);
NSLog(@"Protocol: %@", NSStringFromProtocol(proto));

@end
```

outputs:

```
Protocol: TestProtocol
```

The `@protocol` part of that code is the part I'm not real sure how to do in Swift and if worse comes to worst, you can always bridge to an Objective-C file. Hope this gives you some ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't use a protocol as a key, but you can use a workaround.

```
protocol PropertyStoreKey {
    
    associatedtype Value
    
}

final class PropertyStore {
    
    private var propertyList: [Any] = []
    
    public subscript<K: PropertyStoreKey>(key: K.Type) -> K.Value? {
        get {
            value(of: key)
        }
        set(newValue) {
            update(value: newValue, of: key)
        }
    }
    
    private func value<K: PropertyStoreKey>(of type: K.Type) -> K.Value? {
        guard let index = self.index(of: type) else {
            return nil
        }
        return (propertyList[index] as? PropertyItem<K>)?.value
    }
    
    private func update<K: PropertyStoreKey>(value: K.Value?, of type: K.Type) {
        if let index = self.index(of: type) {
            if let value = value {
                guard var existedItem = propertyList[index] as? PropertyItem<K> else {
                    return
                }
                existedItem.value = value
                propertyList[index] = existedItem
            } else {
                propertyList.remove(at: index)
            }
        } else {
            guard let value = value else {
                return
            }
            let newItem = PropertyItem(type: type, value: value)
            propertyList.append(newItem)
        }
    }
    
    private func index<K: PropertyStoreKey>(of type: K.Type) -> Int? {
        propertyList.firstIndex(where: { $0 is PropertyItem<K> })
    }
    
}

private struct PropertyItem<K: PropertyStoreKey> {
    let type: K.Type
    var value: K.Value
}
```

Usage:

```
struct TimeKey: PropertyStoreKey {
    typealias Value = Double
}

let propertyStore = PropertyStore()
propertyStore[TimeKey.self] = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `AnyHashable`?

```
  protocol SCResourceModel: Hashable {}
  extension SCResourceModel { // Implement the hashable required methods }

  struct SCResource: SCResourceModel {}
```

Now declare a Dictionary like this:

```
 var container = Dictionary<AnyHashable, String>
 contianer[SCResource] = "My first resource"
```

Comment: It'd have to be `container[SCResource.self]` if the protocol metatype is supposed to be the key. But actually, for `AnyHashable` use, it has to be `container[AnyHashable(SCResource.self)]` -- but the protocol type cannot itself be hashable, so this whole approach fails.