# How to work around Swift not supporting first class meta types?

Tags: swift, protocols, existential-type

So I'm implementing the following:

- A simple `LanguageType` protocol, which conforms to `Hashable`
- A `Translateable` protocol, which should allow you to get (and set) a `[String]` from a dictionary, using a `LanguageType` as key

---

```
// MARK: - LanguageType

protocol LanguageType: Hashable {
    var description: String { get }
}

extension LanguageType {
    var description: String { return "\(Self.self)" }
    var hashValue: Int { return "\(Self.self)".hashValue }
}

func ==<T: LanguageType, U: LanguageType>(left: T, right: U) -> Bool {
    return left.description == right.description
}

// MARK: - Translateable

protocol Translateable {
    var translations: [LanguageType: [String]] { get set }
}
```

---

As usual, Swift has a problem with the way the `LanguageType` protocol is used:

[image: Error]

From what I've read, this has to do with Swift not supporting [Existentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), which results in protocols not actually being first class types.

In the context of generics this problem can usually be solved with a type-erased wrapper.
In my case there are no generics or associated types though.

What I want to achieve is to have `translations.Key` to be **any** `LanguageType`, not just one generic type conforming to `LanguageType`.
So for example this wouldn't work:

```
protocol Translateable {
    typealias Language: LanguageType

    var translations: [Language: [String]] { get set }
}
```

For some reason I just can't think of a way to achieve this. I find it sounds like I need some kind of type-erased wrapper, as I want

> `translations.Key` to be **any** `LanguageType`

I think I need to erase the exact type, which is supposed to conform to `LanguageType` in `Translateable`.
What can I do to fix this issue?

---

**Update 1:**
As just determined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34693732/3208492), `LanguageType` actually has associated type requirements (do to it's conformance to `Equatable`). Therefore I will try to create a type-erased wrapper around `LanguageType`.

**Update 2:**
So I've realized, that creating a type-erased wrapper for `LanguageType` won't actually resolve the problem. I've created `AnyLanguage`:

```
struct AnyLanguage<T>: LanguageType {
    private let _description: String
    var description: String { return _description }
    init<U: LanguageType>(_ language: U) { _description = language.description }
}

func ==<T, U>(left: AnyLanguage<T>, right: AnyLanguage<U>) -> Bool {
    return left.description == right.description
}
```

If I now used it in place of `LanguageType` it wouldn't do much, as `Translateable` would still require an associated type:

```
protocol Translateable {
    typealias T
    var translations: [AnyLanguage<T>: [String]] { get set }
}
```

## Solution:

I removed the generic from `AnyLanguage`:

```
struct AnyLanguage: LanguageType {
    private(set) var description: String
    init<T: LanguageType>(_ language: T) { description = language.description }
}

func ==(left: AnyLanguage, right: AnyLanguage) -> Bool {
    return left.description == right.description
}

protocol Translateable {
    var translations: [AnyLanguage: [String]] { get set }
}
```

Not sure why I introduced `T` in Update 2, as it doesn't do anything. But this seems to work now.

Comment: Do you really want to implement equality by comparing hash values? That will never work. The main problem is that you need concrete types. One dictionary cannot work with several classes that have different `hash` implementations.

Comment: A type conforming to `LanguageType` is never supposed to implement it's own version of `hashValue`. Hence `hashValue` is only declared as an extension. Equality would therefore be based purely on names of the Languages, which seems good enough for me.

Comment: Equality cannot be based on hash functions. You always have to compare the strings, not just their hashes.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've changed it

Comment: @MarcusRossel You should probably add your solution as an answer and accept that answer when the 2-day grace period (for accepting ones own answers) is over.

Comment: Is that common practice?

Comment: @MarcusRossel it's not a common practice, it's the only practice :) The place for answers is in the answers section, not within the question, even if one of the answers is yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be a [type-erased wrapper](https://realm.io/news/type-erased-wrappers-in-swift/). Type-erasure fixes the problem of not being able to use [protocols with associated types (PATs)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWoNjiSPqI8&feature=youtu.be&t=1m24s) as first-class citizens, by creating a wrapper type, which only exposes the properties defined by the protocol, which it wraps.

In this case, `LanguageType` is a *PAT*, due to its adoption of `Equatable` (which it conforms to, due to its adoption of `Hashable)`:

```
protocol LanguageType: Hashable { /*...*/ }
```

Therefore it can not be used as a first-class type in the `Translatable` protocol:

```
protocol Translatable {
    var translations: [LanguageType: [String]] { get set } // error
}
```

Defining an associated type for `Translatable` would not fix the problem, as this would constrain the `LanguageType` to be one specific type:

```
protocol Translatable {
    typealias Language: LanguageType

    var translations: [Language: [String]] { get set } // works
}    

struct MyTranslatable<T: LanguageType>: Translatable {
    var translations: [T: [String]] // `T` can only be one specific type

    //...
}
```

As mentioned the solution is a type-erased wrapper `AnyLanguage` (Apple uses the same naming convention for their type-erased wrappers. For example `AnySequence`):

```
// `AnyLanguage` exposes all of the properties defined by `LanguageType`
// in this case, there's only the `description` property
struct AnyLanguage: LanguageType {
    private(set) var description: String

    // `AnyLanguage` can be initialized with any type conforming to `LanguageType`
    init<T: LanguageType>(_ language: T) { description = language.description }
}

// needed for `AnyLanguage` to conform to `LanguageType`, as the protocol inherits for `Hashable`, which inherits from `Equatable`
func ==(left: AnyLanguage, right: AnyLanguage) -> Bool {
    return left.description == right.description
}

// the use of `AnyLanguage` allows any `LanguageType` to be used as the dictionary's `Key`, as long as it is wrapped as `AnyLanguage`
protocol Translateable {
    var translations: [AnyLanguage: [String]] { get set }
}
```

This implementation now allows the following:

```
struct SomethingTranslatable: Translatable {
    var translations: [AnyLanguage: [String]] = [:]
}

func ==(left: SomethingTranslatable, right: SomethingTranslatable) -> Bool { /*return some `Bool`*/ }

struct English: LanguageType { }
struct German: LanguageType { }

var something = SomethingTranslatable()
something.translations[AnyLanguage(English())] = ["Hello", "World"]
let germanWords = something.translations[AnyLanguage(German())]
```

Different types, conforming to `LanguageType`, can now be used as the `Key`. The only syntactical difference, is the necessary initialization of an `AnyLanguage`:

```
AnyLanguage(English())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have protocols as a key for a `Dictionary`, see [Swift Dictionary with Protocol Type as Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901258/swift-dictionary-with-protocol-type-as-key). Swift need to tie the dictionary key to a concrete type.

Seems that you're trying to achieve static polymorphism and dynamic polymorphism in the same construct (the `Translateable` protocol), which I'm not sure it can be achieved.

A workaround would be to declare `Translateable` as a generic struct:

```
struct Translateable<T: LanguageType> {
    var translations: [T: [String]]
}
```

Comment: The struct still wouldn't work, as `T` would end up being one concrete type, and I want `translations.Key` to be any type conforming to `LanguageType`.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you can use an `enum` that conforms to `LanguageType` can mimic the behaviour you're looking for. In that case, you needn't explicitly include conformance to `hashable` in `LanguageType`, as enums are `Hashable`.

```
protocol LanguageType {
    var description: String { get }
    // ...
}

extension LanguageType {
    var description: String { return "\(Self.self)" }
}

enum AnyLanguage : Int, LanguageType {
    case English = 1, German, Swedish
    // implement non-default description
    var description : String {
        return "Language: " + String(self)
    }
}

protocol Translatable {
    var myDict : [AnyLanguage:[String]] { get set }//= [:]
}

class MyFooWordList : Translatable {
    private var myBackendDict : [AnyLanguage:[String]] = [:]
    var myDict : [AnyLanguage:[String]] {
        get {
            return myBackendDict
        }
        set {
            for (k, v) in newValue {
                myBackendDict[k] = v
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
/* Example */
var myFooWordList = MyFooWordList()
myFooWordList.myDict = [.English: ["Hello", "World"]]
myFooWordList.myDict = [.German: ["Hallo", "Welt"]]

print("Words for '" + AnyLanguage.English.description + "': \(myFooWordList.myDict[.English] ?? ["<Empty>"])")
/* Words for 'Language: English': ["Hello", "World"] */

print("Words for '" + AnyLanguage.German.description + "': \(myFooWordList.myDict[.German] ?? ["<Empty>"])")
/* Words for 'Language: German': ["Hallo", "Welt"] */

print("Words for '" + AnyLanguage.Swedish.description + "': \(myFooWordList.myDict[.Swedish] ?? ["<Empty>"])")
/* Words for 'Language: Swedish': ["<Empty>"] */
```

---

Another workaround is to use an `enum`-like class where you can *"dynamically add members"* to this fictive enum

```
class LanguageType {

    class AnyLanguage: Hashable {
        let id: Int
        let description: String

        private init(id: Int, description: String) {
            self.id = id
            self.description = description
        }

        var hashValue: Int { return id } 
    }

    class var ENGLISH: AnyLanguage {
        class English: AnyLanguage {
        }
        return English(id: 1, description: "English")
    }

    class var GERMAN: AnyLanguage {
        class German: AnyLanguage {
        }
        return German(id: 2, description: "German")
    }

    class func CUSTOM(id: Int, _ description: String) -> AnyLanguage {
        return AnyLanguage(id: id, description: description)
    }
}

func == (lhs: LanguageType.AnyLanguage, rhs: LanguageType.AnyLanguage) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

protocol Translatable {
    var myDict : [LanguageType.AnyLanguage:[String]] { get set }//= [:]
}

class MyFooWordList : Translatable {
    private var myBackendDict : [LanguageType.AnyLanguage:[String]] = [:]
    var myDict : [LanguageType.AnyLanguage:[String]] {
        get {
            return myBackendDict
        }
        set {
            for (k, v) in newValue {
                myBackendDict[k] = v
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage

```
/* Example */
var myFooWordList = MyFooWordList()
myFooWordList.myDict = [LanguageType.ENGLISH: ["Hello", "World"]]
myFooWordList.myDict = [LanguageType.GERMAN: ["Hallo", "Welt"]]
myFooWordList.myDict = [LanguageType.CUSTOM(3, "Swedish"): ["Hej", "Varlden"]]
myFooWordList.myDict = [LanguageType.CUSTOM(4, "Finnish"): ["Hei", "Maailma"]]

print("Words for '" + LanguageType.ENGLISH.description + "': \(myFooWordList.myDict[LanguageType.ENGLISH] ?? ["<Empty>"])")
/* Words for 'English': ["Hello", "World"] */

print("Words for '" + LanguageType.GERMAN.description + "': \(myFooWordList.myDict[LanguageType.GERMAN] ?? ["<Empty>"])")
/* Words for 'Language: German': ["Hallo", "Welt"] */

print("Words for '" + LanguageType.CUSTOM(3, "Swedish").description + "': \(myFooWordList.myDict[LanguageType.CUSTOM(3, "Swedish")] ?? ["<Empty>"])")
/* Words for 'Swedish': ["Hej", "Varlden"] */
```

Comment: Sorry, but `Translateable` is really supposed to be a protocol.
And I have also considered using an enumeration storing the languages. But that removes the purpose of `LanguageType`, which should allow addition of new languages in other modules.

Comment: @MarcusRossel I updated my answer with a slightly more protocol-ish solution, but still just an enum. As Cristik writes, you will have a hard time using a protocol as a type.

Comment: You obviously understand, what I'm trying to achieve. But `AnyLanguage` just isn't doable in this case, as it removes the entire flexibility of the code. It's as if Swift's `ErrorType` were not a protocol you could conform to, but an enum listing all the possible error cases. It just wouldn't work.
But thanks for trying

Comment: @MarcusRossel I understand. Perhaps there's some other workaround for this, but I think you'll have to leave trying to user the protocol solution in your question above as a type, if you also want your protocol to be hashable (as explained by Daniel T in your other related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693732/protocol-reported-as-having-self-or-associated-type-requirements-when-it-does)

Comment: @MarcusRossel Added my last go at this for a "workaround", using a "dynamic cases" fictive enum structure. Not exactly what you want, but the last workaround I'll come up with here :)