# Protocol reported as having 'Self or associated type requirements', when it doesn't have any

Tags: swift, protocols

I have the following code:

```
protocol LanguageType: Hashable {
    var description: String { get }
}

extension LanguageType {
    var description: String { return "(Self.self)" }
    var hashValue: Int { return "(Self.self)".hashValue }
}

func ==<T: LanguageType, U: LanguageType>(left: T, right: U) -> Bool {
    return left.hashValue == right.hashValue
}

struct English: LanguageType { }
```

When I do the following:

```
let english: LanguageType = English()
```

I get the following error:

[image: Error]

Where is the associated type supposed to come from?
(Even if I remove the `"\(Self.self)"` it still complains.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Equatable` has `Self` as an associated type requirement and `LanguageType` is indirectly derived from `Equatable`, therefore `LanguageType` has `Self` as an associated type requirement.